# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_category() in line 73. How can I fix this issue?

Tags: php

The full error that I keep getting when trying to run the code is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_category() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ex_starts/ch05_ex1/product_manager/index.php:73 
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ex_starts/ch05_ex1/product_manager/index.php on line 73

Below is the index.php code.

```
<?php
require('../model/database.php');
require('../model/product_db.php');
require('../model/category_db.php');

if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
$action = $_POST['action'];
} else if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
$action = $_GET['action'];
} else {
$action = 'list_products';
}

if ($action == 'list_products') {
// Get the current category ID
$category_id = $_GET['category_id'];
if (!isset($category_id)) {
    $category_id = 1;
}

// Get product and category data
$category_name = get_category_name($category_id);
$categories = get_categories();
$products = get_products_by_category($category_id);

// Display the product list
include('product_list.php');
} else if ($action == 'delete_product') {
// Get the IDs
$product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
$category_id = $_POST['category_id'];

// Delete the product
delete_product($product_id);

// Display the Product List page for the current category
header("Location: .?category_id=$category_id");
} else if ($action == 'show_add_form') {
$categories = get_categories();
include('product_add.php');
} else if ($action == 'add_product') {
$category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
$code = $_POST['code'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$price = $_POST['price'];

// Validate the inputs
if (empty($code) || empty($name) || empty($price)) {
    $error = "Invalid product data. Check all fields and try again.";
    include('../errors/error.php');
} else {
    add_product($category_id, $code, $name, $price);

    // Display the Product List page for the current category
    header("Location: .?category_id=$category_id");
}
} else if ($action == 'list_categories'){
// GET THE CATEGORY DATA and SHOW LIST PRICE
$query = 'SELECT * FROM categories
            ORDER BY categoryID';
$categories = $db->query($query);
include('category_list.php');

} else if ($action == 'add_category') {
//GET THE CATEGORY DATA, VALIDATE INPUT, ADD CATEGORY, SHOW CATEGORY LIST
$category_name = $_POST['category_name'];
//validate
if (empty($category_name)) {
    $error = "Invalid category name. Please try again.";
    include('../errors/error.php');
    //add category
} else {
    add_category ($category_name);
}
header('Location: .?action=list_categories');

} else if ($action == 'delete_category'){
//GET CATEGORYID FROM FORM, DELETE CATEGORY, SHOW CATEGORY LIST
$category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
delete_category($category_id);
header('Location: .?action=list_categories');
}
?>
```

This is the code in categorydb

```
function add_category($category_name){
global $db;
$query = "INSERT INTO categories(categoryName)
     VALUES ('$category_name')";
$db->exec($query); @Barmar
```

Comment: It seems pretty obvious: you haven't defined the function `add_category()`.

Comment: What does the code for `category_list` have to do with this? The problem is `add_category`.

Comment: @Barmar I just updated the full code. Where would i insert add_category()? I don't seem to understand what is wrong.

Comment: Somewhere in the code you need `function add_category($category_name) { ... }` with the implementation of that function.

Comment: It should probably be in one of the files you require at the top, like `category_db.php`.

Comment: That doesn't define the function, it tells it to call the function. But the function doesn't exist.

Comment: That should do it, I don't know why it thinks the function doesn't exist.

Comment: @Barmar Ok thanks I updated the question with the function. Did i miss something

Comment: @Barmar I appreciate the fast help. I cut and paste the same code into the same spot it was and now it works.

Comment: I don't think it really has `@Barmar` in `category_db.php`.  Other than that and the closing `}` that you didn't copy, I don't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: @Barmar lol thanks again for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're not accessing the categor_db.php file you think you are? Add an echo to category_db.php (e.g. `echo $query.'<br>';`) and see if it prints to your page.

If that works, add the following code to index.php on lines 5 and 73:

```
if(function_exists('add_category'))
    {echo 'add_category exists<br>';}
else
    {echo 'add_category does not exist<br>';}
```

Confirm whether the function is defined immediately after call to category_db.php and immediately before you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Is add_category() inside a class?

If so try doing something like `categorydb::add_category()` or `(new categorydb) -> add_category()` (replacing categorydb with the actual class name)